# How to add neighboring elements of 2D array in Python without having to use nested loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, matrix

I want to add neighboring elements "3x3" of an array and create new array. When using nested loops, it takes time since this piece of code will be called thousands of times.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

rows=6
cols=8

array1 = np.random.randint(10, size=(rows, cols))
print(array1)

array2=np.zeros((rows-2,cols-2))

for i in range(rows-2):
    for j in range(cols-2):
        array2[i,j]=np.sum(array1[i:i+3,j:j+3])# print()
        
print("output\n",array2)


##My output
    [[9 4 9 6 1 4 9 0]
     [2 3 4 2 0 0 9 0]
     [2 8 9 7 6 9 4 8]
     [6 3 6 7 7 0 7 5]
     [2 1 4 1 7 6 9 9]
     [1 1 2 6 3 8 1 4]]
    output
     [[50. 52. 44. 35. 42. 43.]
     [43. 49. 48. 38. 42. 42.]
     [41. 46. 54. 50. 55. 57.]
     [26. 31. 43. 45. 48. 49.]]
```

With vectorization, this can be solved. However, I tried different techniques but never had luck with any such as reshaping then adding arrays, using only one loop with size rows or cols.
*note: in my project, the size of rows and cols can be very big.*
it is similar to 2D convolution with kernal of ones.
the question is, **is there anyway to implement this without using loops?** or at least reduce it to have smaller time complexity "to take only rows or cols as size of loop".[image: image for illustration purpose]

Comment: What do you mean by *it is similar to 2D convolution with kernal of ones*? This **is** a 2d convolution with (3,3) kernel of ones for 'valid' slices. Or an avgpool2d with a divisor override or multiplied by pool size.

Comment: it is ture, but I can not directly use convolution since I am doing additional processing to these values. using convolution layers from keras or similar framework/library will restrict me from doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution that i find better for this cases.
Use the function convolve2d from scipy.signal module
I used the function np.ones and np.array to declare your input as a numpy array and used the convolve2d to apply your kernel to each an every part of your image.
This is called [Convolutional Filters and Kernels](https://medium.com/swlh/image-processing-with-python-convolutional-filters-and-kernels-b9884d91a8fd) and it is used a lot in image processing with python.

```
In [50]: import numpy as np

In [55]: np.ones((3,3))
Out[55]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])

In [59]: input_matrix
Out[59]: 
array([[9, 4, 9, 6, 1, 4, 9, 0],
       [2, 3, 4, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0],
       [2, 8, 9, 7, 6, 9, 4, 8],
       [6, 3, 6, 7, 7, 0, 7, 5],
       [2, 1, 4, 1, 7, 6, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 2, 6, 3, 8, 1, 4]])

In [60]: kernel
Out[60]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])

In [61]: from scipy.signal import convolve2d

In [63]: convolve2d(input_matrix, kernel, 'valid')
Out[63]: 
array([[50., 52., 44., 35., 42., 43.],
       [43., 49., 48., 38., 42., 42.],
       [41., 46., 54., 50., 55., 57.],
       [26., 31., 43., 45., 48., 49.]])
```

Also, as a matter of fact the speed of this is quite fast.
As you can see, even in a 1000x1000 matrix it's fast enough.

```
In [68]: %timeit convolve2d(input_matrix, kernel, 'valid')
5.24 µs ± 21.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [69]: input = np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 1000))

In [70]: %timeit convolve2d(input_matrix, kernel, 'valid')
41.6 ms ± 555 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: And I said that It will show effect with larger numbers

Comment: Could you try it with `rows=5000` `cols=7000` `innerRows=700` `innerCols=600`

Comment: not for `6x8` and `3x3`

Comment: I used a 10k x 10k matrix and the results similar tin time to your code using 1k x 1k matrix.

`In [10]: input_matrix = np.random.randint(255, size=(10000, 10000))`

`In [11]: %timeit convolve2d(input_matrix, kernel, 'valid')`
`2.82 s ± 573 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: And make kernel to `700x700`

Comment: I checked your code with `input = np.random.randint(100, size=(rows, cols))`.   and `kernel = np.ones((100, 200))` result is more than    `2 minute`

Comment: I think you are satisfied with that. if you create bigger `kernel = np.ones((100, 200))` it calculates over and over again

Comment: [just read this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10356/computational-complexity-of-2d-convolution)

Comment: Read @Michael Szczesny answer. It explains that partial sum is faster

Answer (score 3):

A micro-benchmark for @trenixjetix's [`convolve2d`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72154073/14277722) solution against a `numpy` implementation of @n-ata's [partial_sum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72153957/14277722). The second approach turns out to be much faster even for relatively small kernels.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

def partial_sum(array1, n):
    array1 = array1.cumsum(1).cumsum(0)
    res = array1.copy()
    res[:,n:] -= array1[:,:-n]
    res[n:] -= array1[:-n]
    res[n:,n:] += array1[:-n,:-n]
    return res[n-1:,n-1:]

rows = 500
cols = 500
n = 50   # relatively small n, since convolve2d becomes slow
np.random.seed(42)
array1 = np.random.randint(10, size=(rows, cols))

%timeit convolve2d(array1, np.ones((n,n), int), 'valid')
#1 loop, best of 5: 1.3 s per loop

%timeit partial_sum(array1, n)
#100 loops, best of 5: 3.36 ms per loop
```

Correctness of `partial_sum` is verified by comparing it with `convolve2d` results.

```
np.testing.assert_equal(partial_sum(array1, n), convolve2d(array1, np.ones((n,n), int), 'valid'))
```

---

Runtime complexity for growing *n*

[image: runtime complexity]

Code used for this benchmark

```
import perfplot

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: (np.random.randint(10, size=(500, 500)), n),
    kernels=[
        lambda a, n: partial_sum(a, n),
        lambda a, n: convolve2d(a, np.ones((n,n), int), 'valid')
    ],
    labels=['partial_sum','convolve2d'],
    n_range=[k for k in range(10,80,5)]
)
```

Comment: You saved my day. I went crazy because I couldn't explain that partial_sum is optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here you should use partial sum. and you could find any point in 1 operation.

If you use it for **small** numbers. There is no a lot of performance difference. But If you check it with **big** numbers. You will see performance difference.

**rows** = count of row

**cols** = count of cols

**innerrow** = your aim row.  `*//in your example(3)*`

**innercol** = your aim col.  `*//in your example(3)*`

With your code:

`O(rows x cols x innerrow x innercol)`

`O(2000 x 2000 x 200 x 2000)`

But you could calculate it with:

`O(rows x cols)`

example: `O(2000 x 2000)`

```
import numpy as np

rows = 1000
cols = 2000

array1 = np.random.randint(10, size=(rows, cols))
array0 = array1
print(array1)

array2 = np.zeros((rows-100, cols-100))

for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(1, cols):
        array1[i][j] += array1[i][j-1]

for i in range(0, cols):
    for j in range(1, rows):
        array1[j][i] += array1[j-1][i]

for i in range(rows-100):
    for j in range(cols-100):
        sm = array1[i+100][j+100]
        if i-1 >= 0:
            sm -= array1[i-1][j+100]
        if j-1 >= 0:
            sm -= array1[i+100][j-1]
        if i-1 >= 0 and j-1 >= 0:
            sm += array0[i-1][j-1]
        array2[i, j] = sm

print("output\n", array2)
```

And here is output

```
[[1 9 1 9 2 0 3 8]
 [7 1 8 7 1 2 8 4]
 [7 1 5 4 8 3 9 0]
 [4 4 8 9 3 1 7 6]
 [2 5 9 9 3 6 7 2]
 [9 0 9 5 0 3 2 8]]
output
 [[40. 45. 45. 36. 36. 37.]
 [45. 47. 53. 38. 42. 40.]
 [45. 54. 58. 46. 47. 41.]
 [50. 58. 55. 39. 32. 42.]]
```

Comment: I think you are missing the point, I want to git ride of or reduce the size/complexity of my nested loops "not making it even larger with more nested loops"

Comment: @Abe Here I just showed performance issue. Your code will slow down when you increase numbers

Comment: @Abe You want to reduce it to have smaller time complexity. Here is solution. Here I wrote more code. But it is `O(rows x cols)` time complexity. In your example you will calculate it again and again for every cell. But in my solution. you calculate it once and use it for each cell.

Comment: This kind of code is not performing enough and misses the point of the task. Tons of ifs each loops are bad, also using normal loops is not fast enough. Also, you are not even using np.sum, which is faster than python normal sum. There are many specialized tools for this kind of tasks. Check my answer.

Comment: I run a %timeit in a 1000x1000 matrix using your code `2.58 s ± 630 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` which is literally seconds, which is unacceptably slow.

Comment: @trenixjetix I just showed the optimal solution. The optimal solution is `partial sum`. I wrote it for example. And you said that `np.sum` is faster than python's normal sum. So try it for `rows=10000` and `cols=10000`. Here is my goal explaining that `partial sum` is better`. You should optimize it. Here I showed without optimization. But still it is faster than before. You shoul optimize it anyway